# Get List of object from a Response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, unmarshalling

I am making a Service call and would like to get the object from it. I am familiar how to do it for an object as follows:

```
Response response = //make service call
Account account = response.readEntity(Account.class)
```

Now if the service call is returning a List of Accounts how can I read the entity from the Response?

```
List<Account> accounts = response.??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with below approach.

```
response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Account>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper for unmarshalling (I don't understand it from your description) you can use that:

```
public <T> List<T>  parseDataList(final String name, final Class<T> clazz) {
    return objectMapper.readValue(
            new ClassPathResource(PATH_TO_SOURCE).getInputStream(),
            objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `ArrayList<Account>` class type

```
List<Account> account = response.readEntity(new ArrayList<Account>().getClass())
```